# How to generate a random matrix in matlab with each value reapating twice?

Tags: matlab, matrix, random

i need to make a random matrix, lets say size 3X4, where the values will be between 1-6, and each value will be reapeted exactly twice (in a random location in the matrix).
 how can i do that?
thanks

Answer (score 9):

You can create an array that contains the numbers 1 to 6 with required repition, say

```
A=[1:6, 1:6];
```

Then shuffle that array using `randperm` and reshape it to a 3 by 4 matrix

```
>> B=reshape(A(randperm(12)), 3, 4)
B =
     5     4     6     1
     2     3     5     4
     6     2     1     3
```

Comment: To answer the OP's question, I'd set `A = repmat(rand(1,6),2,1);`